# I don't understand how to write a linkpattern for scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I am struggling to understand how the link pattern works in scrapy that i got of an example. Has anyone got any ideas on how to write one?

```
def parse(self, response):

    hxs             = scrapy.Selector(response)
    links           = hxs.xpath("//a/@href").extract()        
    #We stored already crawled links in this list
    crawledLinks    = []



    #Pattern to check proper link
    linkPattern     = re.compile("^(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/(?:[\w\.\-\+]+:{0,1}[\w\.\-\+]*@)?(?:[a-z0-9\-\.]+)(?::[0-9]+)?(?:\/|\/(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+)|\?(?:[\w#!:\.\?\+=&amp;%@!\-\/\(\)]+))?$")



    for link in links:
        # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
        if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
            crawledLinks.append(link)
            yield Request(link, self.parse)


    item = MS_homeItem() 
    item['name'] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="product-detail-page"]/li[4]/div/div[2]/h1').extract()
    yield item
```

Any help would be fantastic Thanks James

Comment: Scrapy automatically filters duplicate URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python supports a very common feature known as `regular expressions`(regexes).  Here's a simpler example:

```
import re

strings = [
    "cat",
    "cut",
    "bird",
    "catnip",
    "cute",
]

pattern = r"c.t"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

for string in strings:
    if regex.match(string):
        result = 'yes'
    else:
        result = 'no'

    print("{} => {}".format(string, result))

--output:--
cat => yes
cut => yes
bird => no
catnip => yes
cute => yes
```

In a pattern, a `.` matches any character.

The `linkPattern` is a long complicated pattern that matches things like:

http://www.google.com

as well as more complex urls.  urls can be very complex, which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Comment: Thanks. That really helps.